# react native CLI error : REAKeyboardEventObserver.m (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-cli

I get this error on my terminal:

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Efficio-flliectvckxrsxaybtvppavvdrdv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/REAKeyboardEventObserver.o /Users/melisavadenja/Desktop/Efficio/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/apple/keyboardObserver/REAKeyboardEventObserver.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
```

I have tried installing and reinstalling react-native-reanimated and as well as pod install in the IOS folder. Still nothing works.